# Subscript in Axis description

Tags: java, jfreechart, subscription, chartpanel

I wanted to know if it is possible to use subscript in axis description. I have the following code

```
    XYItemRenderer lineYY = new StandardXYItemRenderer();
    lineYY.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLUE);
    lineYY.setSeriesVisibleInLegend(0,false);
    final NumberAxis yaxY = new NumberAxis("ax [m/s²]");
    yaxY.setRange(-11, 11);
    yaxY.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
    XYPlot plotYY = new XYPlot(datasetY,null,yaxY, lineYY);
    plotYY.setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.TOP_OR_LEFT);
```

Is there a way to subscript the x in the String "a**x** [m/s²]"? An subscript would be e.g.  X₉

Comment: where you got that `²` from? ...coudn't you do it with x

Comment: unfortunately it isnt possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the approach shown [here](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116592), you can specify an [`AttributedString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/AttributedString.html) for the desired axis label. Given a `NumberAxis` named `domain`, the example below uses [`TextAttribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html) values to alter the `SIZE` and `WEIGHT` of some characters, subscripts the second character and superscripts the exponent.

```
String s = "ax [m/s2]";
AttributedString as = new AttributedString(s);
as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE, 24, 0, 2);
as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE, 16, 3, 9);
as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.WEIGHT, TextAttribute.WEIGHT_BOLD, 0, 2);
as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUB, 1, 2);
as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 7, 8);
domain.setAttributedLabel(as);
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent; I've updated the example to illustrate some of the variety possible with [`TextAttribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use unicode values for the subscript/superscript - these should be respected by the Graphics2D rendering of the axis label (via Graphics2D.drawString method). For instance 'X\u2089' would be rendered similar to X₉. This is of course dependent on the Unicode subscript value existing as well as java supporting it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about jFreeChart, but a pure java string could bear that, please try:

```
final NumberAxis yaxY = new NumberAxis("a\u2093 [m/s²]");
```

see: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2093/index.htm

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have tried this already but all i got is an empty box.