# AttributedString in JFreechart Legend, LegendItem

Tags: java, jfreechart, legend

I'm trying to display formatted Strings within JFreeChart's legend.
The [API](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/LegendItem.html#LegendItem-java.text.AttributedString-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-java.awt.Shape-boolean-java.awt.Paint-boolean-java.awt.Paint-java.awt.Stroke-boolean-java.awt.Shape-java.awt.Stroke-java.awt.Paint-)API shows support for this, but however I cannot get it to display.
The aim is to get superscripts, subscripts displayed in jfreecharts legend..

I've written my own renderer and overriden the following:

```
 @Override
public LegendItem getLegendItem(int datasetIndex, int series) {
    LegendItem legendItem = super.getLegendItem(datasetIndex, series);
    AttributedString attString = new AttributedString("s14");
    attString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 10));
    attString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUB, 1,3);
    Shape shape = getLegendBar();
    Paint paint = getBaseFillPaint();
    legendItem = new LegendItem(attString, null, null, null, shape, paint);
    return legendItem;
}
```

But this shows only "s14" as normal string. I need to get the "14" to display in subscript. 
Does anyone know, what I am doing wrong or how to achieve this ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: i added a complete example, which demonstrates what i basically want to do

Comment: See also these [forum threads](http://www.jfree.org/forum/search.php?keywords=LegendItem+AttributedString).

Comment: A related example is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29808858/230513).