# Show complete axis labels in SpiderWebPlot of JfreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

I am creating spider chart using **SpiderWebPlot** of **JfreeChart**.
Axis labels are not displaying in generated image of chart.

What should be done for displaying labels in image?

Here is my code :

```
SpiderWebPlot plot = new SpiderWebPlot(categoryDataSet);
            plot.setStartAngle(90);
            plot.setInteriorGap(0.30);
            plot.setWebFilled(true);
            plot.setBackgroundPaint(new Color (215, 215, 215));
            plot.setOutlineVisible(true);
```

Image generated from above plot is as below:

[image: Generated Image of spider web chart]

Comment: It looks like you crossed out the labels in your image; please clarify; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20SpiderWebPlot).

Comment: @trashgod yeah labels are going off the image, can you tell if they can by put somehow in image only or width provided to the chart? I have already gone through above links.

Comment: I'd override `getPreferredSize()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513).

Comment: http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24530 it helped me to wrap labels on axis of this chart

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188), citing the forum thread. See also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29808858/230513).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
plot.setInteriorGap(0.40);
```

Comment: Please, use English on this version of SO.