# Semi-bold for labels of x and y axis in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am trying to reduce the intensity of bold to text. I find only `Font.BOLD` for title, axis and labels. Can anyone help me to customise the level of BOLD to a text in `JFreeChart`?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29808858/230513), you can use an `AttributedString` for the axis labels. Specify  [`WEIGHT_SEMIBOLD`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html#WEIGHT_SEMIBOLD) to get "A moderately heavier weight than `WEIGHT_REGULAR`."

```
AttributedString as = new AttributedString(s);
…
as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.WEIGHT, TextAttribute.WEIGHT_SEMIBOLD, 0, 1);
as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.WEIGHT, TextAttribute.WEIGHT_BOLD, 1, 2);
```

In this example, the character `a` has `WEIGHT_SEMIBOLD`:

[image: WEIGHT_SEMIBOLD]

In this example, the character `a` has `WEIGHT_BOLD`:

[image: WEIGHT_BOLD]

For reference, `AttributedString` is used in the following:

- [`org.jfree.chart.util.AttrStringUtils`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/util/AttrStringUtils.html).
- [`org.jfree.chart.axis.Axis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/Axis.html) and [`org.jfree.chart.axis.LogAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/LogAxis.html).
- [`org.jfree.chart.LegendItem`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/LegendItem.html), discussed [here](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=11669).
- [`org.jfree.chart.labels.PieSectionLabelGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/PieSectionLabelGenerator.html).